# count frequency of element in dataframe on row wise

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

my data frame is like this

`EMPLOYEE_ID     2020-02-26  2020-02-27  2020-02-28  2020-02-29  2020-03-01
100000074       Absent      Absent      Absent      Present     Absent
100000086       No Match    No Match    Absent      Present     Absent`

and want to be like

```
EMPLOYEE_ID     Absent  Present  No Match 
100000074       4         1        0
```

Plz help

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please show some effort and request for some help, not code!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt('EMPLOYEE_ID')
         .pivot_table(index='EMPLOYEE_ID', columns='value', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
         )
print (df1)
value        Absent  No Match  Present
EMPLOYEE_ID                           
100000074         4         0        1
100000086         2         2        1
```

Another solution with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) per rows in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('EMPLOYEE_ID').apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1)
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int))
print (df1)
             Absent  No Match  Present
EMPLOYEE_ID                           
100000074         4         0        1
100000086         2         2        1
```

Comment: @SanjayGhosh - ya, maybe in future is better add some code, what you try to question for avoid downvotes.