# Counting the frequency a value appears in a Pandas Dataframe ROW

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe that has a row for each user. Each user took a survey that captured scores from 0 - 5 for a series of survey questions. It looks something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['user_a', 'user_b', 'user_c'], 'Cat1_score': [0, 5, 3], 'Cat2_score': [0, 2, 5], 'Cat3_score': [4, 5, 1})
```

I want to count across the row, not the column and I just can't wrap my head around it to call the right method(s).

If I use:

```
df1.count(axis='columns')
```

That just tells me the number of cells that are not NULL.

This following is closer to what I want, but I have 100 different columns to evaluate for each row, and I don't want to manually have to type each out.

```
df1.value_counts('column_name')
```

What I would really like is to end up with a data frame that looks something like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['user_a', 'user_b', 'user_c'], 'zero': [2, 0, 0], 'one': [0, 0, 1], 'two': [0, 1, 0], 'three': [0, 0, 1], 'four': [1, 0, 0], 'five': [0, 2, 1]})
```

I want to count the frequency of how many of the users' respons = 0, or = 1, or = 5 ect. This might be a case of Friday-afternoon-at-work-lack-of-creative-thinking-brain if the answer is obvious.

UPDATE: The suggested answer found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702478/count-frequency-of-element-in-dataframe-on-row-wise) doesn't produce the best output for my needs. The code below produces a very clean data frame that I can use to join with other user tables I have and then save the resulting table to Excel.

Comment: possible duplication of [count frequency of element in dataframe on row wise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60702478/10452700) and [How to get the frequency of a specific value in each row of pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52323435/10452700)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count frequency of element in dataframe on row wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702478/count-frequency-of-element-in-dataframe-on-row-wise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = df1.set_index('User').stack()
out = (pd.crosstab(s.index.get_level_values('User'), s)
         .rename_axis(index='User', columns=None).reset_index()
      )
```

Variant:

```
tmp = df1.melt('User')

out = (pd.crosstab(tmp['User'], tmp['value'])
         .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
     User  0  1  2  3  4  5
0  user_a  2  0  0  0  1  0
1  user_b  0  0  1  0  0  2
2  user_c  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323461/10452700) they offered `out = pd.crosstab(tmp.User, tmp.value.fillna('NaN'))` once using `melt` + `crosstab` approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line using  [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) per rows in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
out = df1.set_index('User').apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

print(out)
#        0  1  2  3  4  5
#User                    
#user_a  2  0  0  0  1  0
#user_b  0  0  1  0  0  2
#user_c  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

Alternatively using [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```py
out = df1.melt('User').pivot_table(index='User', columns='value', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

print(out)
#value   0  1  2  3  4  5
#User                    
#user_a  2  0  0  0  1  0
#user_b  0  0  1  0  0  2
#user_c  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

This answer is inspired by @jezrael; [Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60702503/10452700)

B̶a̶s̶e̶d̶ o̶n̶ [̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ i̶n̶v̶e̶s̶t̶i̶g̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶]̶(̶h̶t̶t̶p̶s̶:̶//s̶t̶a̶c̶k̶o̶v̶e̶r̶f̶l̶o̶w̶.c̶o̶m̶/a̶/7̶6̶0̶0̶2̶0̶6̶1̶/1̶0̶4̶5̶2̶7̶0̶0̶)̶, i̶t̶ s̶e̶e̶m̶s̶ `̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶_̶c̶o̶u̶n̶t̶s̶(̶)̶`̶ i̶s̶ t̶h̶e̶ b̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶ w̶a̶y̶ t̶o̶ g̶o̶ i̶n̶ t̶e̶r̶m̶s̶ o̶f̶ e̶f̶f̶i̶c̶i̶e̶n̶c̶y̶!̶

Comment: Using `apply` on `axis=1` is inefficient. `crosstab` is the equivalent of `value_counts` when you have groups. The scenario for the timings which you referenced is different, this is **without groups**. In this case `value_counts` is indeed the most efficient.

Comment: oh, thanks I was not aware of *with\without group* scenario. I edited my answer. Thanks for this input.